# Server closes only after a few minutes if a request is made in the meantime

Tags: node.js, node.js-connect

I have a server

```
var connect = require('connect');
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');

var HTMLServer = function(path){
    this.path = path;
    this.server = connect().use(serveStatic(this.path));

    this.startServer = function(callback){
        this.server = this.server.listen(8080, callback);
    };
    this.stopServer  = function(callback){
        this.server.close(callback);
    }
}
```

And I use it as follows:

```
var thisServer = new HTMLServer(__dirname);
thisServer.startServer(function(){
    console.log('Server running on 8080...');
    setTimeout(function(){
        thisServer.stopServer(function(){
            console.log('Server closed');
        });
    }, 3000);

});
```

As expected, server starts and after 3000 milliseconds it stops.

**But**, if within these 3000 milliseconds I make a request to this server, the `stopServer` is called, however the server is not closed.

I'm sure this line `this.server.close(callback);` gets executed, but doesn't close the server as I expect.

How can I fix that?

Is a request to the server changing the server instance in a way that needs a special handling?

---

**Later edit:**

I would like to add some precision now that I left the code running. It seems the server **does get closed**, however not instantly, but after an amount of time that I don't understand, no longer than 5 minutes.

So the `close` operation seems to be delayed. Can I make it instant somehow?

Comment: Don't really understand the real problem here.  But, perhaps you want `process.exit()` if you want to instantly shut things down.  Otherwise, node.js keeps running until all existing sockets are finished with their business even if you've closed the server from accepting new connections.

Comment: I might do that, but isn’t there a way to either force close the sockets (I’d rather do that than forcefully exit my process) or at least to see the queue of remaining sockets?

Comment: `process.exit()` will force the sockets closed.  An http server is derived from a `net.Server` so you can use [`server.getConnections()`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_getconnections_callback) on it to get the current number of open connections.

Comment: thanks @jfriend00 - you pointed me in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While @jfriend00 was correct that node.js keeps running until all exiting sockets are finished, the `process.exit` solution was a bit too radical for my use case and I needed a cleaner solution to close the server gracefully.

Looking into `getConnections` only added more confusion since it didn't function as expected. (for example it returned 2 connections even if I didn't make any request).

I also looked into [`server.listening`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_listening) but it returned `false` even if the server accepted more requests. Perhaps accepts connection from a client that made requests before closing the server.

Anyway, the solution for me was to use the [`http-shutdown`](https://github.com/thedillonb/http-shutdown) lib which essentially adds the following `.shutdown` method to your `server` object.

```
function addShutdown(server) {
  var connections = {};
  var isShuttingDown = false;
  var connectionCounter = 0;

  function destroy(socket, force) {
    if (force || (socket._isIdle && isShuttingDown)) {
      socket.destroy();
      delete connections[socket._connectionId];
    }
  };

  function onConnection(socket) {
    var id = connectionCounter++;
    socket._isIdle = true;
    socket._connectionId = id;
    connections[id] = socket;

    socket.on('close', function() {
      delete connections[id];
    });
  };

  server.on('request', function(req, res) {
    req.socket._isIdle = false;

    res.on('finish', function() {
      req.socket._isIdle = true;
      destroy(req.socket);
    });
  });

  server.on('connection', onConnection);
  server.on('secureConnection', onConnection);

  function shutdown(force, cb) {
    isShuttingDown = true;
    server.close(function(err) {
      if (cb) {
        process.nextTick(function() { cb(err) });
      }
    });

    Object.keys(connections).forEach(function(key) {
      destroy(connections[key], force);
    });
  };

  server.shutdown = function(cb) {
    shutdown(false, cb);
  };

  server.forceShutdown = function(cb) {
    shutdown(true, cb);
  };

  return server;
};
```

With this function, I can update my server as follows, and now `stopServer` works as expected:

```
var HTMLServer = function(path){
    this.path = path;
    this.server = connect().use(serveStatic(this.path));
    this.startServer = function(callback){
        this.server = addShutdown(this.server.listen(8080, callback));
    };

    this.stopServer  = function(callback){
        console.log("I was called");
        this.server.shutdown(callback);

    }
}
```